# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'debiteurnaam' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I am using Laravel FIlament v3 and i created migrate model resource that were working but when i added more String in migrate and more Textinput i get a error.
I did try adding every string a ->nullable(); but then in View page i dont see any data (but i dont get the error)
when I want to create data in the website I get doesn't have a default value
Before (code that worked)
Migrate

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('test01s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('Bedrijf_user');
            $table->string('Domain');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('test01s');
    }
};
```

Model

```
class Test01 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        "Bedrijf_user",
        "Domain",
    ];
}
```

Resource

```
class Test01Resource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Test01::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';

    protected static ?string $recordTitleAttribute = "name";

    // public static function getGloballySearchableAttributes(): array
    // {
    //     return ["name", "Bedrijf_user","Domain"];
    // }

    // public static function getGlobalSearchResultUrl(Model $record): string
    // {
    //     return Test01Resource::getUrl('edit', ['record' => $record]);
    // }

    public static function getGlobalSearchResultDetails(Model $record): array
    {
        return [
            'Bedrijf_user' => $record->Bedrijf_user,
            'Domain' => $record->Domain,
        ];
    }

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(50),
                TextInput::make("Bedrijf_user")
                    ->required(),
                TextInput::make("Domain")
                    ->required(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('name'),
                TextColumn::make("Bedrijf_user"),
                TextColumn::make("Domain"),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListTest01s::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateTest01::route('/create'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewTest01::route('/{record}'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditTest01::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}
```

After (does not work)

Migrate

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('test01s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('debiteurnaam');
            $table->string('BedrijfUser');
            $table->string('Domain');
            $table->string('Where');
            $table->string('UserName');
            $table->string('Password');
            $table->string('Notes');
            $table->string('Db');
            $table->string('Kvk');
            $table->string('Btw');
            $table->string('Email');
            $table->string('Phone');
            // $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('test01s');
    }
};
```

Model

```
class Test01 extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        "BedrijfUser",
        "Domain",
        "Where",
        "UserName",
        "Password",
        "Notes",
        'Db',
        'Kvk',
        'Btw',
        'Email',
        'debiteurnaam',
        'Phone',
        'created_at',
    ];
}
```

Resource

```
class Test01Resource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Test01::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-building-storefront';

    protected static ?string $navigationGroup = 'Bedrijven';


    protected static ?string $recordTitleAttribute = "debiteurnaam";

    public static function getGloballySearchableAttributes(): array
    {
        return ["debiteurnaam","Domain"]; // here you can add what u want to search with
    }

    //this is for when u click u can go to edit

    public static function getGlobalSearchResultUrl(Model $record): string
    {
        return Test01Resource::getUrl('edit', ['record' => $record]);
    }

    public static function getGlobalSearchResultActions(Model $record): array
    {
        return [
            Action::make('view')
                ->url(static::getUrl('view', ['record' => $record])),
            Action::make('edit')
                ->url(static::getUrl('edit', ['record' => $record])),
            // Action::make('quickView')
            //     ->dispatch('quickView', [$record->id])
        ];
    }

    public static function getGlobalSearchResultDetails(Model $record): array
    {
        return [
            'BedrijfUser' => $record->BedrijfUser,
            'Domain' => $record->Domain,
        ];
    }

    // public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    // {
    //     return $panel
    //         // ...
    //         ->globalSearchKeyBindings(['command+k', 'ctrl+k']);
    // }

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Repeater::make('Algemeen')
                    ->schema([
                        TextInput::make('debiteurnaam')
                            ->maxLength(50)
                            ->required(),
                        TextInput::make("BedrijfUser"),
                        TextInput::make("Kvk"),
                        TextInput::make("Btw"),
                        TextInput::make("Db"),
                    ])
                    ->deletable(false)
                    ->addable(false)
                    ->columns(1),

                Repeater::make('Contactpersonen')
                    ->schema([
                        TextInput::make("Email")
                            ->email(),
                        TextInput::make("Domain")
                            ->prefix('https://')
                            ->suffixIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-up-on-square-stack'),
                        TextInput::make("Phone")
                        ->tel(),
                    ])
                    ->deletable(false)
                    ->addable(false),

                Repeater::make('Passwords')
                    ->schema([
                        TextInput::make("Where"),
                        TextInput::make("UserName"),
                        TextInput::make("Password")
                            ->password()
                            ->autocomplete(false),
                    ])
                    ->columns(1)
                    ->reorderableWithButtons(),

                Repeater::make('Note')
                    ->schema([
                        MarkdownEditor::make('Notes'),
                    ])
                    ->columns(1)
                    ->reorderableWithButtons(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('BedrijfUser')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('Domain'),
                TextColumn::make('Where'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListTest01s::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateTest01::route('/create'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewTest01::route('/{record}'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditTest01::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}
```

when i am in the website than i go to new so i can make some data everything is working tel i want to click create than i get the error
(I am using Laravel Filament v3 so i think that its automatic the code mad to create Model and  the only think i need to create a model is CMD open and type `php artisan make:model name`)

```
https://github.com/Ahmad-MHK/crm-vidian/tree/3v-test01-Textinput-Build_error
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are actually creating the model, most likely the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using repeaters for your form, this is what the filament docs say about it:

> We recommend that you store repeater data with a JSON column in your database. Additionally, if you're using Eloquent, make sure that column has an array cast

So that's probably the problem, it converts the repeaters to some sort of array and that can't be saved, because you're just editing the model.

I see you also add:

```
->deletable(false)
->addable(false)
```

to the repeaters. I think you're looking for a Section or maybe a Fieldset, have a look at the available Layouts for splitting the different forms (https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/layout/getting-started).

So changing you Repeater::make() to a Section::make() should be to solution.